# How to back out of mass update in SQL Replication

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

We have a database which is set up in Merge Replication.

We accidentally updated hundreds of thousands of records in a large published table on the publisher database. We did something like this:

```
update LargeTable
set Field = Field
```

So basically, every record got updated to be the same - *no data was actually changed*. However, every record in the table is now being delivered to every subscriber and the whole system has come to a halt. We are very worried this will take days and days to complete.

How can we safely remove data from the `msmerge_contents` and `msmerge_genhistory` table? Are there other system replication tables to remove records from? I can see the exact records in these tables that refer to the mass update. I just don't want to remove them without knowing it is safe to do so.

Comment: *"Are there other tables to remove records from?"* how can someone else answer that?

Comment: Other system replication tables

Comment: Does it have backup databases?

Comment: It's a massive database and would take many hours to restore, as well as being heavily used with data changing all the time. We are hoping there's a way to just tell replication not to bother to distribute those updates to the subscriber, as there's nothing to actually update.

Comment: It's a massive database and would take many hours to restore, as well as being heavily used with data changing all the time. We are hoping there's a way to just tell replication not to bother to distribute those updates to the subscriber, as there's nothing to actually update.

Comment: I just went through this a few weeks ago with transactional replication. The solution is to reinitialize, unfortunately.

Comment: Another hack would be to find out the transactions that are not sent to distributor using `sp_replcmds` and `sp_repltrans` and then run `sp_repldone` - Updates the record that identifies the last distributed transaction of the server.

Answer (score 3):

There is no supported way to achieve what you want to do, aside from complete reinitialization. That said, you *might* be able to achieve a shortcut and retain a supported configuration, but only under direction of a Microsoft support engineer. Attempting to modify the system replication tables without that guidance risks compounding your current problems.

My advice would be to open a case under your support contract, or take the hit of reinitializing and change operating practices to prevent a recurrence of the problem in future.

Comment: Paul, I agree, this is one for MS. I wondered if there was a fairly easy way to achieve this.